# Python Flask-Mail: smtplib.SMTPServerDisconnected: Connection unexpectedly closed

Tags: python, smtp, gmail

I'm working with a contact page tutorial (https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/intro-to-flask-adding-a-contact-page--net-28982) where the user fills out a form and flask-mail uses one of my emails to send the info to another one of my emails. When I tested the code on a localhost server, it works fine and it sends to my gmail, but when I tried sending a form to my gmail on an ubuntu server, it returns smtplib.SMTPServerDisconnected: Connection unexpectedly closed. Does anyone know the reason for why it works locally, but not on a server? I also made sure to turn on less secure apps on for my gmail too.
Heres my code for routes.py:

```
from app import app
from flask import render_template, Flask, send_file, redirect, request, flash
from app.forms import ReplyForm
import webbrowser
from flask_mail import Message, Mail

mail = Mail()
app.secret_key = ''

app.config["MAIL_SERVER"] = "smtp.gmail.com"
app.config["MAIL_PORT"] = 465
app.config["MAIL_USE_SSL"] = True
app.config["MAIL_USERNAME"] = '[email@gmail.com]'
app.config["MAIL_PASSWORD"] = '[password]'

mail.init_app(app)


@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@app.route('/index', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def index():
    form = ReplyForm()

    if request.method == 'POST':
        if form.validate() == False:
            flash('All fields are required.')
            return render_template("index.html", contactsHash=True,form=form)
        else:
            msg = Message(form.subject.data, sender='email@gmail.com', recipients=['anotheremail@gmail.com'])
            msg.body = """
            From: %s <%s> 
            %s
            """ % (form.name.data, form.email.data, form.comment.data)
            mail.send(msg)

            return render_template('index.html', success=True, contactsHash=True, form=form)  
    
    elif request.method == 'GET':
        return render_template('index.html', form=form)
```

And here's the error I get from uwsgi when I try to submit the form on my server:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/jerry/portfolio/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", li                                                                                                                                   ne 2073, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/home/jerry/portfolio/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", li                                                                                                                                   ne 1518, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "/home/jerry/portfolio/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", li                                                                                                                                   ne 1516, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "/home/jerry/portfolio/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", li                                                                                                                                   ne 1502, in dispatch_request
    return self.ensure_sync(self.view_functions[rule.endpoint])(**req.view_args)
  File "/home/jerry/portfolio/./app/routes.py", line 33, in index
    mail.send(msg)
  File "/home/jerry/portfolio/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask_mail.py", l                                                                                                                                   ine 491, in send
    with self.connect() as connection:
  File "/home/jerry/portfolio/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask_mail.py", l                                                                                                                                   ine 144, in __enter__
    self.host = self.configure_host()
  File "/home/jerry/portfolio/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask_mail.py", l                                                                                                                                   ine 165, in configure_host
    host.login(self.mail.username, self.mail.password)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/smtplib.py", line 707, in login
    self.ehlo_or_helo_if_needed()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/smtplib.py", line 605, in ehlo_or_helo_if_needed
    (code, resp) = self.helo()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/smtplib.py", line 434, in helo
    (code, msg) = self.getreply()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/smtplib.py", line 398, in getreply
    raise SMTPServerDisconnected("Connection unexpectedly closed")
smtplib.SMTPServerDisconnected: Connection unexpectedly closed\
```

Comment: some servers may block access to other portals for security reason - they want to block spamers/hackers. And also GMail may block access from some servers - also for security reason - to block spamers/hackers.

Comment: is there a way to allow access for gmail? I turned on less secure apps and apparently that's supposed to work, but I still get an error.

Comment: if your server blocks access to Gmail then you would have to change server. But I can't confirm if server blocks access.

Answer (score 1):

for me all i had to do was to add `app.config['MAIL_USE_TLS'] = False app.config['MAIL_USE_SSL'] = True` this line to send email just verify your spam to see it